# Nano vs Vim or Vi

Tags: vim, nano

I have been using `nano` for quite a while now and I prefer using it anyway. But still I don't understand why people still emphasize on `vi` or `vim`. Can anybody specify me the reason why `vim` editor is preferred over `nano` editor?

Comment: This is matter of taste, and everyone prefers what he/she like.

Comment: Have a look at this link https://danielmiessler.com/blog/differences-vi-vim-emacs/

Comment: I get trapped, I keep hitting `ESC:wq` and nothing happens, “random” characters appear in my newly crafted sudeors file, beads of sweat start forming. Will I ever get out? Will that weird combination of :wquxxBcE matter if I escape? <pulls plug> … … …

Answer (score 2):

You are free to choose whichever editor that you like.

`nano` is much easier to use than `vi`, but `vi` is also much more powerful and features an elaborate set of macro programming commands, mass operations, multiple cut&paste buffers, and more.

Comment: `nano` is much easier to **learn** than vi (because there's very little to learn).  `vi` is much easier to **use** (because it is far more capable).  If someone limits themselves only to tools that are easy to learn, they will always be doing things the hard, laborious, time-consuming way.